# T-SQL How to return X item of Total items

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table where these values appear:

```
-------------------------------
Id | Name   | Type | Date
-------------------------------
1  | Nick   | 1    | 13/11/2020
2  | Peter  | 1    | 13/11/2020
3  | Thomas | 2    | 13/11/2020
4  | Mike   | 2    | 13/11/2020
5  | Kelly  | 3    | 13/11/2020
6  | Nicky  | 3    | 13/11/2020
```

I would like to have as an output:

```
1  | Nick   | 1 | 13/11/2020  Type 1/2
2  | Peter  | 1 | 13/11/2020  Type 2/2
3  | Thomas | 2 | 13/11/2020  Type 1/1
4  | Mike   | 3 | 13/11/2020  Type 1/3
5  | Kelly  | 3 | 13/11/2020  Type 2/3
6  | Nicky  | 3 | 13/11/2020  Type 3/3
```

So I would like have the "row number" of each type together with this type total.
How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
    row_number() over(partition by type order by name) rn,
    count(*)     over(partition by type) cnt
from mytable t
order by type, name
```

It is unclear how you want to order rows having the same `type`: this uses column `name`.